# PHP Random Array with Text, Image and Image Alt attribute

Tags: php

I've just made a random array that pulls information from this code. It does work but I'm trying to put in the alt attribute in the image so that it's more accessible for people with screen readers etc.

```
<?php 
  $funfacts[0]['image']="img/fun-fact-white-potato.jpg"; 
  $funfacts[0]['paragraph']="White potatoes were first cultivated by local Indians in the Andes Mountains of South America.";
  $funfacts[0]['alt']="White Potato";

  $funfacts[1]['image']="img/fun-fact-strawberries.jpg"; 
  $funfacts[1]['paragraph']="Strawberries are not really a fruit or a berry but the enlarged receptacle of the flower. ";
  $funfacts[1]['alt']="A pair of Strawberries";

  $funfacts[2]['image']="img/fun-fact-oranges.jpg"; 
  $funfacts[2]['paragraph']="British sailors used to be called &ldquo;Limeys&rdquo; because they ate citrus to prevent scurvy on long sea voyages.";
  $funfacts[2]['alt']="A cut-up Orange"; 

  $funfacts[3]['image']="img/fun-fact-carrots.jpg"; 
  $funfacts[3]['paragraph']="The original carrots used to be purple. Farmers in Holland started planting orange carrots in the sixteenth century."; 
  $funfacts[3]['alt']="A pile of carrots";

  $id_funfacts = array_rand($funfacts); 

  echo  "<img src='".$funfacts[$id_funfacts]['image']. "' alt='".$funfacts[$id_funfacts]['alt'] "' >"; 
  echo  "<p>".$funfacts[$id_funfacts]['paragraph']. "</p>"; 
?>
```

It tells me that the line with

```
echo  "<img src='".$funfacts[$id_funfacts]['image']. "' alt='".$funfacts[$id_funfacts]['alt'] "' >";
```

is the culprit but I'm not sure what's wrong with it. You can see that I'm not really a PHP guru if I could not solve this problem.

I look forward to hearing back from you.

James

Comment: What exactly is the error you're getting?

Comment: I just found the error, as I found that I did not include a full stop on the error line after .$funfacts[$id_funfacts]['alt]

Comment: I was just about to put that in the answers :)

Comment: Hehe, thanks. I think it's telling me to go to bed..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I basically found that I had missed a full stop after this line of code.

```
echo  "<img src='".$funfacts[$id_funfacts]['image']. "' alt='".$funfacts[$id_funfacts]['alt'] "' >";
```

The correct code is:

```
echo  "<img src='".$funfacts[$id_funfacts]['image']. "' alt='".$funfacts[$id_funfacts]['alt']. "' >";
```

If I'm missing something simple like that, it's time for bed then!!

Comment: These are the best kind of errors, because everyone, no matter their experience, makes them.